# Is single sql statement always atomic in innodb?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

There is a sql like that

> UPDATE xxx SET num = num -1 WHERE num > 0;

Will this be an atomic operation even if I have no transaction statement?

> Can this sql ensure the num field always be non-negative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If autocommit is enabled, yes it will be executed atomically. Every statement will be a single transaction unless autocommit is disabled.

It should be noted that autocommit is enabled by default, hence why START TRANSACTION is usually necessary to initiate a transaction.

Comment: Can this sql ensure the num field always be non-negative?

Comment: Yes, it will. If you're getting negative results from this query, you should check to make sure autocommit is enabled. `select @@autocommit;` should return 1.

Comment: thinks a lot. Autocommit is actually enabled. The I will use this sql to prevent a negative number appeared while my system is concurrently visted